# Fork a repository transferrred to another user

Tags: git, github

I have recently transferred two repos from my github account, one to an organization where I am owner, the other to a different user (making him the maintainer of the package).
Can I now fork these two repositories to my own account, in order to collaborate via fork-and-pull? Or would that overwrite some git settings/redirects, so I instead need to collaborate via opening branches on the new forked repo (I have push access both places)?

Comment: Have you tried to fork?

Comment: Make your question more readability...

Comment: Thanks DoNhuVy . @0andriy yes I tried to fork the organization one, it worked but I deleted it again because when dealing with it locally git treated both my fork and the one at the organization as the same remote. There is also this warning: " you create a new repository under your account with the same name as the transferred repository, existing redirects to the transferred repository will break. Instead, use a different name for the new repository." here: https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-transfers/ 
I am not sure whether this applies though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fork the repo under a different name. Your fork does not have to have the same name as the forked repo, so just give it a new name on forking and the redirects of the original name should work properly, as your new fork has a different name.